# How to recover all protein ses into refseq database

Tags: ncbi

I'm actually trying to download all the virus protein sequences available in the NCBI database.

I guess the link is this one: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/viral/

How could I get all the protein sequences in fasta format into one file ? Does someone have codes to do that easily?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe that this question belongs to StackOverflow, as it's not about biology or related interdisciplinary subjects. Also for such tasks I recommend using Scrapy for Python

Comment: @MaximKuleshov — Better on SE Bioinformatics than Stack Overflow as nobody on SO will know anything about the file format of Genbank files. And leave it at that. Recommending a package in a particular language is not appropriate in a comment and not much use anyway if the poster doesn't use the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most things, there are multiple ways to do this. Here are two of them:

#### Download from the NCBI Assembly portal

- Go to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/ and search for 'Viruses[Organism]'. For our purposes, I am going to restrict this search to Virus assemblies that are latest RefSeq and reference genomes. The query for this will be: `"Viruses"[Organism] AND "latest refseq"[filter] AND "reference genome"[filter]`. It will return 46 results.
- To download the protein FASTA sequences for all of these, click on the big blue `Download Assemblies` button, choose `RefSeq` as source and `Protein FASTA` as File Type.
- Click the Download button and a tarball with FASTA files - one for each assembly - will be created for you to download. You will then have to combine them all into a single file. 
  [image]

#### Download using wget

- Go to ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/viral and download the `assembly_summary.txt` file. This is a tab-delimited file with information about every RefSeq viral assembly located in that FTP path. Column 20 has the FTP path for the assembly which you can parse out and use wget to download the protein FASTA file for each assembly, followed by combining them into a single gzipped file as shown below:

  ```
  ## download the assembly_summary.txt file
  wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/viral/assembly_summary.txt
  ## download the protein FASTA files
  grep -v '^#' assembly_summary.txt \
      | cut -f20 \
      | while read -r url ; do wget $url/*_protein.faa.gz ; done
  ## combine all files into a single one
  zcat *_protein.faa.gz | gzip > all_viral_proteins.faa.gz
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, it did work. Unfortunalty when I `try zcat *_protein.faa.gz | gzip > all_viral_proteins.faa.gz` I get : `-bash: /usr/bin/zcat: Argument list too long`

Comment: Finally I found I way by doing : for i in $(ls | grep "_protein.faa.gz");do cat $i >> all_viral_proteins.faa.gz;done

Comment: Interesting. I never had to concatenate so many files! Is there a reason why you want such a large number of sequences in a single file? Can you not work with multiple files? Presumably, the single file would be very big and may not be the easiest to handle for downstream usage.

Comment: It is because I'll make a blast with those sequences as queries, so I'll make a blast database with them.

Comment: Maybe you can help me again, I would like to download a list of genomes, I have their ID number (list with one ID number by line) and I would like to get all the genomes in .fa format do you know if it is possible with the same script?

Comment: What kind of IDs do you have? Can you give me a couple of examples?

Comment: Yes of course: 
'Genome ID:  12051
Genome ID:  39971
Genome ID:  44840
Genome ID:  55512
Genome ID:  39899
Genome ID:  65382'

Comment: Where did you get these IDs from? They don't seem to be the NCBI Assembly UIDs because when I search for 12051[All UIDs] in the [NCBI Assembly](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/?term=12051[All+Uids]) I don't see any results. Would it be possible to get GCF or GCA accessions for these genomes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87950/discussion-between-kayvee-and-grendel).